# CD burning tool capable of overburning

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-8

I need a program on Windows 8, that can Overburn DVD+Rs in order to create a OS X Maverics bootable DVD. My DVD+Rs only have 4.7GB space but i need 5GB.

Needed features:

- Free
- Working on Windows 8
- should be able to overburn both CDs and DVDs

Comment: Could you please tell us what is your goal with overburning? Copy protection? Data removal? Recycle failed DVD-R? Your goal will help us answer better.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not want to hear this, but...
Unless u got some kind of "special"-non-standard-DVD+R-alike disks you wont be able to get 5gb of data onto a single 4,7 GB disk!

In fact the space on a DVD+R is only about **4,37 GiB** *(Windows reports this inaccurately as GB)*
Disk manufacturers use the SI system so **1 MB = 1000 kB** whilst Windows uses a binary conversion so **1MiB = 1024 kiB**

Thus your so called **4.7 GB** disk actualy has only **4,37 GiB** capacity.

If you're still interested in overburning you have to scale down your expectations: AFAIK you can overburn about 10~30 MB depending on the tool and your DVD-Burner hardware.

If your hardware supports it:
I'd recommend you get youself some **Double-Layer DVD+R** Disks to solve your problem. They are labeled with **8.5GB** capacity, so you would actualy have about **7,91 GiB** of useable disk space.